# Nodejs Mysql: Accessing variable in another route

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I'm building a simple e-wallet system that accepts user's phone number and query's the user's wallet from database and displays balance; I built a form that receives a phone number and uses the number to query the database for user id and uses that id to query his/her e-payment wallet id but i can't pass the wallet to a get request to render the wallet balance and username

```
router.post('/',function (req, res, next) {
  var sql = `SELECT UsrID FROM users WHERE UsrPhone =  ${req.body}`;
  var query = connection.queryValue(sql, function (err, userid) {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log('User ID: ' + userid);

    var sql = `SELECT * FROM wallet WHERE UserID = ${userid}`;
    var query = connection.queryRow(sql, function (err, wallet) {
      if(err) throw err;
      console.log('WalletID: ' + wallet.WalletID);
      //send walletID to get route
      res.redirect('/wallet/:id');
    });
  });
});

router.get('/wallet/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  var sql = `SELECT * FROM wallet WHERE WalletID = ${wallet.WalletID}`;
  var query = connection.queryRow(sql, function (err, wallet) {
    if(err) throw err;
    res.render('wallet', {title: 'Wallet', wallet});
  });
});
```

but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Just a quick side note, those queries are really bad.  Both because you don't limit the returned fields, but more because you're allowing for a pretty trivial SQL Inject attack. Exceptionally bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't pass the current `WalletID` to the redirect route. You should pass the id to redirect URL like this:

```
res.redirect('/wallet/' + wallet.WalletID);
```

So, the `wallet/:id` can get the current `WalletID` and make the query base on that.

And you can run the query like this:

```
  var sql = `SELECT * FROM wallet WHERE WalletID = ${req.params.id}`;
```

Comment: its throwing an error TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value

Comment: Which line exactly? try the console.log `wallet.WalletID` and `req.params.id`, what will you get? Are they the correct values?

Comment: i was passing req.body to the first query instead of req.body.phone